# Getting screen bounds in diffrent orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Say my device is in portrait mode when using:

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
```

I get the bounds of the device in portrait

How can i get the screen bounds for landscape without changing screen to landscape?

Comment: use observer for orientationChange and deal portrait vs landscape orientations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let portrait = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let landscape = CGRectMake(0, 0, portrait.size.height, portrait.size.width)
```